# Why is java giving me this NullPointerException?

Tags: java, plugins, nullpointerexception, minecraft, bukkit

Ok, so I've been using Eclipse to work on making a Bukkit plugin for Minecraft. For some reason, I have been getting a lot of seemingly unreasonable NullPointerExceptions. I found that NullPointerExceptions occur when you attempt to use a the values and functions of the type of a varriable whose value is null. I could not find it in my code, so I wanted to see if someone else could find it.

Error:

```
20:16:58 [SEVERE] java.lang.NullPointerException
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at com.tommy3244.plugins.MakeYourOwnBlocks.MakeYourOwnBl
ocks.onDisable(MakeYourOwnBlocks.java:73)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlug
in.java:219)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.disablePlugin
(JavaPluginLoader.java:481)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(S
implePluginManager.java:400)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugins(
SimplePluginManager.java:393)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.clearPlugins(Si
mplePluginManager.java:434)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.reload(Craf
tServer.java:563)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:184)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(Rel
oadCommand.java:23)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCo
mmandMap.java:186)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.dispatchCom
mand(CraftServer.java:514)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.dispatchSer
verCommand(CraftServer.java:506)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedServer.al(Dedica
tedServer.java:260)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedServer.r(Dedicat
edServer.java:225)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.q(Minecra
ftServer.java:494)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.run(Minec
raftServer.java:427)
20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.ThreadServerApplication.r
un(SourceFile:849)
```

And here is my actual plugin code:

```
package com.tommy3244.plugins.MakeYourOwnBlocks;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

import org.bukkit.block.*;
import org.bukkit.command.*;
import org.bukkit.configuration.ConfigurationSection;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.*;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class MakeYourOwnBlocks extends JavaPlugin implements Listener
{
    public Map<NewItem, List<ItemStack>> items;
    public File configfile;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public void onEnable()
 {
      try
        {
          Map<List<Map<String, Object>>, NewItem> smap;
            smap = SaveLoadAPI.load(this.getDataFolder().getPath()+"\\Items.data");
          for(List<Map<String, Object>> maps : smap.keySet())
            {
              NewItem item = smap.get(maps);
             List<ItemStack> stacks = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
               for(Map<String, Object> map : maps)
              {
                  stacks.add(ItemStack.deserialize(map));
                }
              items.put(item, stacks);
           }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
     {
          items = new HashMap<NewItem, List<ItemStack>>();
       }
      try
        {
          this.getDataFolder().mkdirs();
     }
      catch(Exception e)
     {
          
       }
      configfile = new File(getDataFolder(), "config.yml");
        if(!configfile.exists())
       {
          saveResource("config.yml", false);
       }
      try
        {
          getConfig().load(configfile);
      }
      catch(Exception error)
     {
          getLogger().severe("Could not load config!");
            error.printStackTrace();
       }
      getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
     getLogger().info("MakeYourOwnBlocks successfully enabled!");
 }
  public void onDisable()
    {
      try
        {
          Map<List<Map<String, Object>>, NewItem> smap = new HashMap<List<Map<String, Object>>, NewItem>();
          for(NewItem item : items.keySet())
         {
              List<ItemStack> stacks = items.get(item);
                List<Map<String, Object>> stacks2 = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
              for(ItemStack stack : stacks)
              {
                  stacks2.add(stack.serialize());
                }
              smap.put(stacks2, item);
           }
          SaveLoadAPI.save(smap, this.getDataFolder().getPath()+"\\Items.data");
       }
      catch (Exception e)
        {
          getLogger().severe("Was unable to save the items file to the default path of: "+this.getDataFolder().getPath()+"\\Items.data");
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
  }
  @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
    public void onItemStackRightClick(PlayerInteractEvent e)
   {
      Player player = e.getPlayer();
     //getLogger().info("Player "+player.getName()+" has right clicked.");
      for(NewItem item : items.keySet())
     {
          for(ItemStack curstack : items.get(item))
          {
              ItemMeta lore = ((ItemStack)curstack).getItemMeta();
               List<String> lore2 = player.getItemInHand().getItemMeta().getLore();
             if(lore == null || lore2 == null)
              {
                  getLogger().info("Pointer null!");
                   if(lore == null)
                   {
                      getLogger().info("Pointer 1 null");
                  }
                  else
                   {
                      getLogger().info("Pointer 2 null");
                  }
              }
              if(lore2.equals(lore))
             {
                  getLogger().info(player.getDisplayName()+" right clicked with the same item!");
                  boolean right = e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK;
                  boolean block = e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK || e.getAction() == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK;
                 boolean worked;
                    if(right)
                  {
                      worked = item.onRightClick(player, right, block);
                  }
                  else
                   {
                      worked = item.onLeftClick(player, right, block);
                   }
                  if(!worked)
                    {
                      player.sendMessage("Script fault! Error raised.");
                   }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
   {
      if(sender instanceof Player)
       {
          
       }
      else
       {
          sender.sendMessage("You must be a player to perform this command!");
         return false;
      }
      if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("makeitem"))
       {
          if(args.length < 4)
         {
              return false;
          }
          String name = args[0];
         String type = args[1];
         String data = args[2];
         String damage = args[3];
           try
            {
              int dmg = Integer.parseInt(damage);
                byte dta = (byte)Integer.parseInt(data);
               int id = Integer.parseInt(type);
               if(getConfig().contains("items."+name))
              {
                  ConfigurationSection section = getConfig();
                    List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                  lines.add(null);
                   lines.add(null);
                   if(getConfig().contains("items."+name+".onrightclick"))
                    {
                      List<String> cur = getConfig().getStringList("items."+name+".onrightclick");
                     lines.set(0, cur);
                 }
                  else
                   {
                      lines.set(0, null);
                    }
                  if(getConfig().contains("items."+name+".onleftclick"))
                 {
                      List<String> cur = getConfig().getStringList("items."+name+".onleftclick");
                      lines.set(1, cur);
                 }
                  else
                   {
                      lines.set(1, null);
                    }
                  List<ItemStack> stacks = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
                   ItemStack stack = new ItemStack(id, 1, dta);
                   ItemMeta meta = stack.getItemMeta();
                   meta.setDisplayName(name);
                 List<String> lore;
                   if(getConfig().contains("items."+name+".description"))
                 {
                      lore = getConfig().getStringList("items."+name+".description");
                    }
                  else
                   {
                      lore = new ArrayList<String>();
                  }
                  lore.add(name);
                    NewItem item = new NewItem(lore, name, id, dta, lines, dmg, false, section);
                   meta.setLore(lore);
                    stack.setItemMeta(meta);
                   getLogger().info(stack.toString());
                    stacks.add(stack);
                 if(items == null)
                  {
                      getLogger().info("unused");
                  }
                  items.put(item, stacks);
                   Player player = (Player)sender;
                    player.getLocation().getWorld().dropItem(player.getLocation(), stack);
                 player.sendMessage("Here you go!");
              }
              else
               {
                  sender.sendMessage("No configuration section at \""+"items."+name+"\"");
                   return true;
               }
          }
          catch(Exception error)
         {
              //sender.sendMessage("Error: "+error.getLocalizedMessage());
             //System.out.println(error);
               //throw error;
             //makeitem test 272 0 0
                error.printStackTrace();
               return true;
           }
          sender.sendMessage("Error: No command specified");
       }
      return true;
   }
}
```

UPDATE:

nakib answered my question, and the error is fixed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If Java is giving you a `NullPointerException`, then you're trying to use a `null` object as though it was not `null`. What line in your code generates the exception?

Comment: @JackManey Did you look at the error? It says line 73.

Comment: Why should I count lines on a non-[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 73, you have

```
for(NewItem item : items.keySet())
```

The property `items` is null when `onDisable()` is called.

To solve this, you should initialize the `items` on declaration

```
public Map<NewItem, List<ItemStack>> items = new HashMap<NewItem, List<ItemStack>>();
```

Comment: But how is that possible? OnEnable sets it. It even has a try/catch block to make sure it's set! How is this happening????

Comment: Probably onEnable() is only called after onDisable(). And also, it will fail at onEnable() and then the catch block will initialize the property.

Answer (score 1):

The `items` variable must be `null`. You could potentially fix it with this at the top of your class:

```
public Map<NewItem, List<ItemStack>> items = new HashMap<NewItem, List<ItemStack>>();
```

You look like you have a couple areas where you assume it's been initialized, so I'd either do it at the top of the class, or in your constructor (Which doesn't exist yet :)).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, I'd wager `items` (on line 73) is null, and you call for its values. Add something to make sure that the method doesn't get called if the for block on line 28 doesn't get run at least once.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is telling you that the `NullPointerException` is coming from:

```
    20:16:58 [SEVERE] java.lang.NullPointerException
    20:16:58 [SEVERE]       at com.tommy3244.plugins.MakeYourOwnBlocks.MakeYourOwnBl
    ocks.onDisable(MakeYourOwnBlocks.java:73) <-- HELPFUL ADVICE FROM STACK TRACE


68     public void onDisable()
69        {
70          try
71            {
72              Map<List<Map<String, Object>>, NewItem> smap = new HashMap<List<Map<String, Object>>, NewItem>();
73              for(NewItem item : items.keySet()) <--- THIS LINE IS PUKING, SO items is probably null!
```

It's critical that you learn how to interpret these messages, as well as step through your code in a modern IDE using the debugger.  Without these tools, you're not really equipped to navigate large code bases.

Another piece of advice I'd give is that `smap` is not very object oriented.  Some sort of encapsulation would help here so you don't need a `Map` of a `List` of a `Map` of a.....what were we talking about again?